# How can the submitted values in a POST message be accessed in Rust/Iron framework?

Tags: rust, iron

I am using a form which uses the `POST` method to submit the input. Is it possible to access the input like accessing a dictionary? I think there must be a better way than parsing the request body.

Comment: I am wondering if [bodyparser::Json](http://ironframework.io/doc/bodyparser/struct.Json.html) can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`params`](https://crates.io/crates/params/) crate for this.

With this crate, you can get the POST parameters with:

```
let params = req.get_ref::<Params>();
```

(See the [example](https://github.com/iron/params/blob/master/examples/params.rs) for a complete code.)